# Calling method using $http Post in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call the method ProcessCriteria in AngularJS below but for some reason I am keep getting error message:

> VM18010:1 POST http://example.com/api/TalentPool/ProcessCriteria 404
>   (Not Found)

Below is my Calling code:

```
    var param = { 'Item': item.Key, 'SolrLabel': SolrLabel };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/TalentPool/ProcessCriteria',
            data: param
            //headers: {
            //    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            //}
        }).then(function (response) {
                // success
                console.log('Facet Data Posted');
                return response;
                                    },
                function (response) { // optional
                    // failed
                    console.log('facet post error occured!');
                });
```

And my Server side method:

```
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult ProcessCriteria(string Item, string SolrLabel)
        {

            var itm = Item;
            var solr = SolrLabel;

            return Ok();
        }
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: 404 means the page you are trying to post on does not exist. You probably have a mistake in the URL.

Comment: are you sure api endpoint up and running - try adding simple GET method to see if you can hit it in browser.

Comment: the url is correct as I am able to navigate to it through browser.

Comment: ASP.net cannot match your request in its `Route Table` because you have 2 parameters in your action and the router doesn't understand it. see my answer.

Comment: Did you try e.g. `console.log(param);` to see if you are sending correct data?

Comment: @JamesP Yes I have checked the console and am getting the parameter values correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got i working, below is the code for others if they get stuck on it.

```
   var pvarrData = new Array();
            pvarrData[0] = JSON.stringify(item.Key);
            pvarrData[1] = JSON.stringify(SolrLabel);
            pvarrData[2] = JSON.stringify($localStorage.message);


                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/TalentPool/ProcessCriteria',
                    data: JSON.stringify(pvarrData),
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                }).then(function (response) {
                        // success
                        console.log('Facet Data Posted');
                        return response;
                                            },
                        function (response) { 
                            // failed
                            console.log('facet post error occured!');
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`ASP.net` cannot match your request in its `Route Table` because you have 2 parameters in your action and the router doesn't understand it.

it expects a data object that your parameters warp to this.

First of all, make a Model like it:

```
public  class Criteria
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string SolrLabel { get; set; }
}
```

then change your action:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ProcessCriteria(Criteria criteria)
{
    var itm = criteria.Item;
    var solr = criteria.SolrLabel;
    return Ok();
}
```

## Update

and update your javaScript part with `JSON.stringify`:

```
var param = { 'Item': item.Key, 'SolrLabel': SolrLabel };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/TalentPool/ProcessCriteria',
            data: JSON.stringify(param)
            //headers: {
            //    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            //}
        }).then(function (response) {
                // success
                console.log('Facet Data Posted');
                return response;
                                    },
                function (response) { // optional
                    // failed
                    console.log('facet post error occured!');
                 });
```

Comment: Will mark it negative because reply doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @ShK  did you find your problem? did you get my answer?. did you test it? :)

Comment: So how do I pass the criteria object from AngularJs $http?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class as said by in above answer and you can pass data in http post like this

```
 var obj = {
            url: url,
            async: true,
            method: 'POST',
           headers: {
                 "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               }
            };
            if (typeof data != 'undefined' || typeof data != null) {
                obj.data = data;
            }
            $http(obj).then(function(response){
            },function(error){
            });
```